# How To Troubleshoot "Code 2" MS Errors?

Tags: installation

I am trying to install Google Earth Pro on a Win10 v1903 build 18362.418 and it just won't go.  Stops now at 'error code 2'  and I'm informed this means 'file not found'.

How can I troubleshoot this?  I'm thinking I need to discover what file it is looking for.  Is there a kind of internal 'packet sniffer'  that will monitor what the Google Installer is trying to do, perhaps?

Comment: Process Monitor by Sysinternals/MS

Comment: it really is just like a packet sniffer alright.

Comment: Found a process thread that opens a registry key and then queries a subkey of that key.  The subkey is not found.   Thread exits with a 'status 2'.

Could that be the 'file not found' and the 'code 2' error?

Comment: There are many keys that are queried for and not found so I can’t say. Depends what the key is. It seems unlikely but maybe.